# Needing help optimizing Linq-to-SQL with nested associations and SUM

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ that I would like to make more performant.  The query I am running currently is

```
item.ShipmentLines.Where(p => p.Shipment.TxnDate < dt).Sum(p => p.Quantity);
```

Where `ShipmentLines` is associated with an item object, and `ShipmentLines` are associated with `Shipments` all through the .NET entity framework.

What I am finding when running this and looking at the generated SQL is that it is making a query to check the Shipment.TxnDate where clause for each associated shipment and then returning all of the matching shipmentlines records back to the server to then run the SUM.  What I would like it to do is something more like

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity)
  FROM ShipmentLine sl
  LEFT OUTER JOIN shipment s ON s.ShipmentId = sl.ShipmentId
  WHERE sl.itemid = @itemid
  AND s.TxnDate > @dt
```

`itemid` above being the id of the object that is calling the LINQ code above.

I have not been able to coerce LINQ to optimize this query into a single statement that is fairly simple to do directly in SQL.

Does anyone know how to optimize this to generate the single statement above?

Edit:  Generated code for the LINQ above
 Here is the generated SQL.

```
SELECT [t0].[ShipmentLineId], [t0].[ShipmentId], [t0].[Quantity], [t0].[ItemId], ..all the other columns..
FROM [dbo].[ShipmentLine] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ItemId] = @p0
```

and then this a few thousand times for all the related shipments

```
SELECT [t0].[ShipmentId], [t0].[TxnDate], ..all the other columns..
FROM [dbo].[Shipment] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ShipmentId] = @p0
```

Comment: Can you please post the generated SQL so that it's easy for readers to compare generated SQL vs what is optimized require SQL?

Comment: Have you tried creating a LINQ-ish left outer join (with a `DefaultIfEmpty` call). You can look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins or any of several Stack Overflow posts

Comment: @user1672994 see above for generated code

Comment: @Flydog57 I haven't tried that yet as it seemed sad to go that route to create my own associations in the LINQ when the entities already have that association.  I may give it a shot just to see if that works.

Comment: @JasonDaniels what is `item` and why do all queries contain an `ItemId` in the Where clause? The question's LINQ query *can't* produce any of the SQL queries posted here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Shipments contain ShipmentLines, and Shipmentlines contain Items.  This is the Item itself determining how many of itself have been on Shipments earlier than a certain date, so I'm needing to get the sum of all the quantity of the shipment lines that have contained this item.  I promise this code is what is generated by the linq above, as I had a trace on the database checking all the queries that were being ran during this time.  I only removed most of the db columns as there are many on both tables in the queries above.

Comment: @JasonDaniels that's not what I asked. Is it a DbContext? A LINQ query? Something else? That LINQ query will never emit `WHERE sl.itemid = @itemid`, unless the line is only part of a larger query

Comment: Perhaps I'm not experienced enough with the .NET world to clearly explain this, but I'll try:  I'm calling this on an entity framework object (item) that has associations through the framework.  My understanding is that this is LINQ syntax, and I do have a db context in this area of the code, but I'm not calling that directly here.  The original item object was retrived via that context.

Comment: also, that is the statement.  It is not part of any larger query.

Comment: @JasonDaniels - What if you change the query as `item.ShipmentLines.Include(s => s.Shipment).Where(p => p.Shipment.TxnDate < dt).Sum(p => p.Quantity);`?

Comment: That doesn't compile as ShipmentLines does not have a definition for Include:  'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Database.ShipmentLine>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Database.ShipmentLine>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)